# Basic question on (regular) conditional probablities.

Tags: probability, measure-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$ be a measure space and $P(A|\mathcal{C})$ be the conditional probability of $A$ under $\mathcal{C}$.
A regular conditional probablity is a conditional probablity that is also a measure for every fixed $\omega\in\Omega$.
Let $(A_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in\mathcal{A}$ with $A_{i}\cap A_{j}=\emptyset\ \forall i\neq j $. We then know that:
\begin{equation*}
 P(\bigcup \limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_{n}) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} P(A|\mathcal{C}) \quad P\text{-a.s.}
\end{equation*}
But somehow this is not a measure for fixed $\omega\in\Omega$? At least that's what I've read in books but the explanations were very short unfortunately.
Let's say $(A_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq\mathcal{A}$.
Then:
\begin{equation*}
 P(\bigcup \limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_{n}) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} P(A|\mathcal{C}) \quad \text{ for all } \omega\in  N^{c}, \text{ for some } N\in\mathcal{C} \text{ with } P(N)=0.
\end{equation*}
Then for all $\omega\in\Omega$ it holds:
\begin{equation*}
 1_{N^{c}}P(\bigcup \limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_{n}^{i}) = 1_{N_{i}^{c}}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} P(A|\mathcal{C}),
\end{equation*}
($1_{N}$ is an indicator function). We could do this even for uncountable many sequences.
Then wouldn't this be a measure for fixed $\omega\in\Omega$ if we let $A$ run?
Thanks for your help, I'v been thinking about this for days but can't wrap my head around it.